# It's possibile to synchronyze two distant clock?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

is there a way to have two space clocks synchronized? and if the answer is yes, if it travels towards me in a uniform rectilinear way (and from its perspective I will do the same) what will our clocks mark when we meet if the time dilation is symmetrical?

Comment: Do you mean in practice or in theory is it possible to synchronize clocks? Have you read this article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light

Comment: It's not obvious what you mean by synchronize.  If the two clocks aren't moving with respect to each other, then yes, the two observers can agree that their clocks are the same.  But if they are moving with respect to each other, then no, as each will observe the other clock to be moving more slowly.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Einstein synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation)?

Comment: So e.g. A Is moving and B Is at rest, of both comunicate each other the time what they will se?

Answer (score 0):

There's no sense to "the time dilation is symmetrical".  The time dilation is relative.  If the clocks agree at the meeting point that's the best you can do.  Whether they agree when they are apart is motion dependent and since all motion is relative there is no fact-of-the-matter about the synchrony of distant clocks, even if they are not moving relative to one another.  If they are not moving relative to one another, then they can be synchronized by assuming the light signal velocity is the same in both directions.  But that synchrony only applies at rest their frame.  And there is no direct measurement that can show the speed of light is the same in both direction, as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light

But it is also shown that no experiment will contradict an assumption that the speed of light is isotropic.  The Michelson-Morely experiment already shows that the two-way speed of light is isotropic.  The abberation of starlight shows that the one way speed doesn't vary with the speed of the source or the speed of the Earth thru the aether.  So the only other reasonable theory is that the emitted, outbound speed is different from the returning speed.  But that would be contradicted by the use of radar repeaters. So while it is possible in any particular of measurement of light speed that the one-way speeds are different; there isn't any coherent theory of what this difference would be, nor any reason to assume it's not zero.

Comment: So what happen if two distant clock (which are synchronized) move towards each other? If both can assume that the other Is moving, when they will meet who Is right?

Comment: Both are right.  They just measured the proper time along different paths thru spacetime.